# Does the Lorentz contraction have measurable physical qualities?

Tags: special-relativity

I am interested in the Sagnac effect which showed that light travels a greater distance in an apparatus that is moving with it. Does this mean length contraction is not a physically measurable quantity? On a related issue is there any evidence supporting physical shortening on rotating discs? What is the current status of this debate?

Comment: There is no debate at this point. The idea of length contraction as a dynamic effect was entertained by [Larmor and Poincaré in the waning days of the ether theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction#History), to which [Sagnac was partial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagnac_effect#History), and so he misinterpreted his own experiment. The modern view is that contraction is a purely kinematic effect, which essentially measures the extent to which the classical notion of "length" is inadequate (space distance is not relativistically invariant).

Comment: One can, of course, construct an argument that magnetic induction follows from length contraction though this is just a long-winded way of saying that the electromagnetic field is a skew-symmetric second-rank tensor field and the Lorentz contraction maps it into a group through the usual similarity transform. Or something like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Proof of Lorentz contraction?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166932/proof-of-lorentz-contraction)